# Frequently updated data in JWT

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization, microservices

If i keep the users roles inside of his JWT for example, and i want the update to be immediate and not just wait for the JWT to expire, is the only answer here to blacklist his current JWT and make him refresh it?

Comment: The question is if this is really is a requirement or if it is a nice to have requirement? It makes everything more complicated to have to deal with this requirement.  Or just have a  access token with a short lifetime, like 5-10 minutes... So when they get their new role, you just tell them to take a cup of coffe.

Comment: Not really a requirement, a workaround is to just not have it in the JWT and check the db or cache. My question was really would this be a viable solution and if it's not is there any other way to avoid checking the db every time and just check the payload from the JWT

Answer (score 0):

The question is if this is really is a requirement or if it is a nice to have requirement? It makes everything more complicated to have to deal with this requirement. Or just have a access token with a short lifetime, like 5-10 minutes... So when they get their new role, you just tell them to take a cup of coffee.

To support this requirement, the complexity of your architecture and application will increase.

Sometimes its better to just following along with the initial design philosophy of OpenID Connect and accept this shortcoming. Fighting unnecessary complexity is a constant battle in every system and probably your time is better spent elsewhere.

Also, the performance of your system will be much better by not having to query each time a token is processed.